# accessing cloudfront file with IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

I have stored a file on s3 using CloudFront to restrict its access.Now, it is not publically open as I wanted.
Now, I want to access that file using IAM roles. Is it possible to access an s3 object which is stored using CloudFront via IAM roles?

Comment: I assume/ you assume you noticed something called OAI throughout configuration of Cloudfront distrubtion with your S3 bucket. If so , take a look at : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

you can extend and grant permission to CloudFront bucket policy. Please find a sample policy and official documentation below,

```js
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Id":"PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":" Grant a CloudFront Origin Identity access to support private content",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be"},
       "Action":"s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
     }
   ]
}
```

Please have a look on official documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-6)